# Stored Procedure output result set

Tags: oracle, plsql

Apologies for the newbie question, I am writing an Oracle stored procedure that opens a cursor for a specific SQL, calculates some variables for each row returned by the cursor but the stored procedure should return as a result set these variables that have been calculated for each row returned by the cursor. I am a bit confused on how to do this - can anyone help?!

Comment: What will consume the returned result set? A SQL query? A stored procedure? A Java application using JDBC? Something else?

Comment: Look up Cursor Variables and Pipelined functions. One of these two features should be the solution you are looking for. The documentation is available online at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/ I would think you would want to start with the PL/SQL manual.

Comment: Actually the result set is read by an ETL tool, Informatica. I just couldn't find a way of outputting the variables to a result set

Answer (score 0):

I did read some of it so far I have something like this (just a trimmed down example and not exact code) but just need to return v_calc and v_calc_res in a result set:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure sp_test
(
 in_input in number,
 out_return out sys_refcursor
)  
as 
v_calc number;
v_calc_res number;
 CURSOR C_test IS 
      select blah from test where blah  = in_input;
begin
  open c_test
  loop
  fetch c_test into v_calc;
   v_calc_res := v_calc*5;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a procedure to return a reference cursor for the calling routine to consume the procedure itself cannot then consume it. Cursors, including reference cursors are 1 way, 1 time consumables. As for as the desired calculations, they can be added to select defined for the  cursor. So:

```
-- setup 
create table test (blah integer, blah_stuff varchar2(50) );

-- build sp 
create or replace procedure sp_blah_text(
                  in_input  in number
                , out_cur  out sys_refcursor
                )
is
begin 
    open out_cur for
         select blah, blah_stuff, blah*5 as blah_x_5
           from test
          where blah = in_input;
end sp_blah_text; 

-- test data 
insert into test(blah, blah_stuff)
  select 1,'a' from dual union all
  select 2,'b' from dual union all 
  select 2,'x' from dual union all 
  select 2,'z' from dual union all   
  select 3,'c' from dual;

-- test 
declare
   ref_cur  sys_refcursor;
   l_blah   test.blah%type;
   l_stuff  test.blah_stuff%type;
   l_blah_5 test.blah%type; 
begin
   dbms_output.enable(null);
   sp_blah_text(2,ref_cur);
   loop
      fetch ref_cur
       into l_blah
          , l_stuff
          , l_blah_5;
      exit when ref_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('blah=' || l_blah || ',stuff=' || l_stuff || ',blah*5=' || l_blah_5);
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works a treat thank you very much. I now have a performance issue that maybe you could help with. When I open the cursor, I then run several other SELECT statements to retrieve values using the variables from the cursor (see below). I assume this is because the switch between PL/SQL and SQL engine. Would using table collections help? But as I see since I need different columns from different tables I would need to have several different collections, how could I output everything in one record?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure sp_test
(
 in_input in number
)  
as 
v_calc number;
v_calc_res number;
v_blah_blah number;
v_blah_blah_blah number;
v_blah_blah_blah number;
 CURSOR C_test IS 
      select blah from test where blah  = in_input;
begin
  open c_test
  loop
  fetch c_test into v_calc;

select blah_blah into v_blah_blah from t_blah_blah;

select blah_blah_blah into v_blah_blah_blah from t_blah_blah_blah;

select blah_blah_blah_blah into v_blah_blah_blah_blah from t_blah_blah_blah_blah;

    v_calc_res := v_calc*5*v_blah_blah*v_blah_blah_blah*v_blah_blah_blah_blah
  end loop;
end;
```